# Keycloak login page refresh logs out from other tab

Tags: keycloak, identityserver4, oidc-client-js

we are using OIDC-client library from react js side and IS4 using keycloak as login provider,

1. open the two tabs and open the same url[e.g. xyz.com]
2. when 1st tab request the url, IS4 provides the login page from keycloak.
3. user log in with code provided by keycloak and IS4 redirect to correct url. [ all good]
4. the second tab is still on login page, by pressing f5 on tab2 should bring the same page as SSO in nature, f5 works fine here but there is signredirectcallback failure on tab1 which trigger frame window timeout and logout happens on tab1.

due to that 1st tab also gets signout.

any clue?

Comment: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL from signinredirectcallback, but why tab1 signinredirectcallback happens when tab2 is refreshed,

Comment: Do you have multiple instances of the client or IS4?

Comment: no, single instance, it seems some scope is removed from connect/authorize/callback? api...    f5 triggers the whole sign in api and call external/callback which has the all scope but in b/w scopes are lost and left with only openid.